# Hindi text is not visible completely in Inno Setup WelcomeLabel2

Tags: fonts, inno-setup, hindi

Text is not visible completely due to fixed height of labels. The below character of each word in *"खुली & हुई"* is improper due to height of `WelcomeLabel2`. The language is Hindi. I used the same .islu file available on Inno Setup official website. In other languages like French, German etc., the text is correct.

```
[Languages] 
Name: "hi"; MessagesFile: "D:\Hindi.islu"; LicenseFile: "D:\license-hi.rtf"
```

[image: Text is not clear]

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem even in Windows Notepad, when I open `Hindi.islu`:

[image]

So it seems to be problem with the font or Windows rendering of the font. Not Inno Setup issue.

---

It cannot be due to height of `WelcomeLabel2` as its height spans all three lines. There are not separate labels for each line. Set `WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Color := clRed;` and you will see:

[image]